# Xsens Device API function 'startRecording' fails

Tags: python, sensors, wireless

I'm trying to write Xsens Device API Python code for reading live data from three MTw sensors connected to a Awinda2 USB Dongle. However, the library function `startRecording` fails every time. I've tried numerous rearrangements without success. My OS is Linux. The question is, how to make the function work as expected.

EDIT: I removed the code as the answer explains the issue without any need for specifics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that some Xsens Device API functions require their own try-except blocks around them to work in Python. That solved the issue.